# I want to aggregate the data depending on the updated_on timestamp in jpql but invalid keyword INTERVAL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hql, jpql

I want to aggregate the data depending on the updated_on timestamp which should take aggregation over 2 hour interval in JPQL.The query works fine in postgres pgadmin.

I have used the query:

```
@Query("select DATE_TRUNC('day',srisk.updatedOn)+cast(DATE_PART('hour',srisk.updated_on) as Integer)/2*INTERVAL '2 hour' as updatedOn,avg(srisk.riskValue) as riskValue FROM SiteRisk srisk WHERE srisk.updatedOn BETWEEN :fromDate and :toDate and srisk.siteId =:siteId group by 1 order by 1 desc")
```

But it is saying invalid keyword near INTERVAL.
How do I solve this?

Comment: That might be valid **SQL**  but it's not valid **JPQL**. You will either need to use a native query (overcoming the limitations of JPQL) or do this in Java

Comment: Is there no way to take the interval by alternate way in jpql only?

Comment: No idea. I don't use obfuscation layers (aka "ORM") precisely because of those limitations that won't let me use even simple SQL features

Comment: you can use native query for sql

Comment: Will I be able to use native query for JPARepository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just specify the interval as a variable, for example in this case interval '2 hour' is 120 minutes. It may not be 120 minutes, it can be 2 hours too, try and verify your results. Like this -

```
select pg_catalog.date(a.sale_date) || ' ' || cast(cast(DATE_PART('hour',a.sale_date) as Integer)/2*2 as text) || ':00:00' as date1, avg(sale) as riskValue 
    FROM test1 a group by 1 order by 1 desc;
```

This will return date in the text form, but it can be read as timestamp in jpa or it has to be converted to timestamp, either way. I have used a different table and column names, please make necessary modifications.

Or just use a native query in your JPA call.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-

All the JPA implementations support this.

Comment: It will be helpful if you elaborate your solution.

Comment: Edited my answer.